# How to populate Google Form title field with value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am looking for a way to pass values to several Google Form "Question Title".

I have a form where some of the questions need to be populated with a value-- here is an example:

***Question Title***: For the fiscal year ending «fiscal_year_14», what were your total grant payments?

Where **«fiscal_year_14»** would be a date (12/31/2014) that I have stored on a Google Spreadsheet.

Is this possible with [Google form](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) / [Google App Scripts](https://www.google.com/script/start/) ?

Comment: If you want to "Pre-Fill" some input fields, but not others, that is possible.  The PreFilled form can only be pre-filled from search string parameters in the URL.  The way that the end user gets their form prefilled is by using the link.  There is no other way to prefill a Google Form.  So, the code would need to get the item ID, and construct the link URL.  So instead of using the "built-in" method to get a pre-filled URL, you can build the URL from code.  OR, I suppose that you could add or delete item responses in code, submit the new response, then use the prefill method.

Comment: I think @spencerEaston has a good approach, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet of code that can modify the title of a question. This opens the active form, gets all the items, check the items for your particular token, then replaces it with correct date. This function can be ran manually or as a scheduled task. Note: Scripts can not be triggered by the active form in any way.

```
function updateQuestion() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(),
      items = form.getItems(),
      title = "",
      token = "«fiscal_year_14»",
      HardCodeDate = "12/31/2014"; // you would look this up in your spreadsheet.

  for(var i in items){     
     title = items[i].getTitle();     
     if(title.indexOf(token) != -1){
        items[i].setTitle(title.replace(token, HardCodeDate));
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: hmmm interesting that looks like it would work for me I would just need to iterate through the rows and capture the date column instead of the `HardCodeDate`